# How can I see how many comp FFA games I played?

Tags: overwatch

Is there a way to find out how many comp FFA games did I play? I know that there is “games won” stat for comp FFA, but it only counts games where you finished first. And there is no “games played”. I thought that maths could help me, but there is also no “avg per game” stat.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to just select the Comp FFA Stats in the career profile *overview* tab, and then select the yellow "*View Leaderboard* button":

[image: View Leaderboard]

Then look yourself up by checking the "*Only Friends*" box in the upper right corner:

[image: Only Friends checkbox]